# wcf service runs fine in java project, but fails in android project

Tags: java, android, wcf

I have build a wcf web service. When I consume this service in a java project build using eclipse it runs fine but when i try to consume it in android project it gives an exception.

Here is how I am consuming it in java project.

Step 1: Create directory org and com using wsimport and include it in src folder of java project.

Step 2: Add the external jars present in sub-folder "lib" of folder "metro"(This folder is actually referring to the folder where I have installed the metro framework). For this goto project->properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add external jars and then browse and select these jar files.

Step 3: Create a new class to communicate with the web service. Here is the class that I am using.

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import org.tempuri.IService1;
import org.tempuri.Service1;


public class JavaClient {
    public static void main(String[] strArgs)
    {

    try
    {
        Service1 service1 = new Service1(new URL("http://192.168.1.18/WcfService/Service1.svc?wsdl"), new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "Service1"));
        IService1 port = service1.getBasicHttpBindingIService1();
        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://192.168.1.18/WcfService/Service1.svc");
        int input = 100;
        String strOutput = port.getData(input);
        System.out.println(strOutput);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Now when I run this java project it ran successfully.

Now I want to do the same for an android project. So in the same manner as above I create an android project which is using android platform 2.2 as the build target and then I follow step 1 and step 2 as described above. Thereafter I create a class having the following code.

```
package android.client;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import org.tempuri.IService1;
import org.tempuri.Service1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidClientJavaServerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try
        {

            Service1 service1 = new Service1(new URL("http://192.168.1.18/WcfService/Service1.svc?wsdl"), new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "Service1"));
            IService1 port = service1.getBasicHttpBindingIService1();
            ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://192.168.1.18/WcfService/Service1.svc");
            int input = 100;
            String strOutput = port.getData(input);
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    strOutput, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
       }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After it when I run this android project the application fails in executing successfully.
Here is the detailed output of running this android application.

```
07-05 19:50:24.864: W/dalvikvm(279): Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/tempuri/Service1; (68)
07-05 19:50:24.864: W/dalvikvm(279): Link of class 'Lorg/tempuri/Service1;' failed
07-05 19:50:24.864: E/dalvikvm(279): Could not find class 'org.tempuri.Service1', referenced from method android.client.AndroidClientJavaServerActivity.onCreate
07-05 19:50:24.864: W/dalvikvm(279): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 85 (Lorg/tempuri/Service1;) in Landroid/client/AndroidClientJavaServerActivity;
07-05 19:50:24.864: D/dalvikvm(279): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
07-05 19:50:24.864: D/dalvikvm(279): VFY: dead code 0x000a-0045 in Landroid/client/AndroidClientJavaServerActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
07-05 19:50:25.044: D/AndroidRuntime(279): Shutting down VM
07-05 19:50:25.081: W/dalvikvm(279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.tempuri.Service1
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.client.AndroidClientJavaServerActivity.onCreate(AndroidClientJavaServerActivity.java:21)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-05 19:50:25.124: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to look at this post!!
http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects